# Injecting dependencies using ninject in a wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject, datacontext

I'm using ninject (extensions) to inject dependencies in a wcf service. What scope must I use for injecting `IDataContext` dependency since I get "The context cannot be used while the model is being created." error when using `InRequestScope()` ?

```
Bind<IDataContext>().To<DataContext>().InRequestScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", "TestDB");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2011/08/16/dependency-injection-ninject-wcf-service.aspx) out. I found it very helpful getting DI working with Ninject with WCF Service. It's a very basic example with minimal code to get you going.